# How to reload python modules on python-shell-send-buffer in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

When I use `python-shell-send-buffer` (C-c C-c) I can see changes from my main buffer in python shell.

But if my buffer has imported modules they are not reloaded.  How can it be fixed?

For exmple:
**main.py:**

```
from functions import foo
print 'a'
```

**functions.py:**

```
def foo():
    print 'bcdef'
```

So if I change `foo()` and run `python-shell-send-buffer` on main.py - it gives me the same `foo()` it read 1st time

```
a
bcdef   # never changed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this - use ipython.

Create configuration "dev" (or whatever):

```
ipython profile create dev
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: u'/home/username/.config/ipython/profile_dev/ipython_config.py'
```

And add these lines to "ipython_config.py":

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

Then set variables in Emacs config for python-mode:

```
(setq
   python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
   python-shell-interpreter-args "--profile=dev"
)
```

IPython started with this config will reload modules when you resend code to it.

Comment: When I press `C-c C-p` the console opens with the following error: `IPython profile: dev

^[[6n^[[JIn [1]: ^[[8D^[[8C`.
Maybe it is related to `%autoreload 2`, what is the meaning of the `%` symbol and of `2`?